# Explain a MySQL Query to me

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a tough time figuring out exactly how the following mysql query works

```
SELECT dp.name, COUNT(em.dp) as employees 
FROM dp LEFT JOIN em ON dp.name=em.dp 
GROUP BY dp.name 
HAVING COUNT(em.dp) = 2;
```

It's just showing what departments have exactly 2 employees. Here are the two tables:

```
em
----
id
full_name
dp


dp
----
id
name
```

These are a few entries I have input.

```
INSERT INTO em (full_name, dp) VALUES ('Chris', 'ENG'), ('Steve', 'HR'), ('Mike', 'ACC'), ('Marvin', 'ACC');
INSERT INTO dp (name) VALUES ('ENG'), ('HR'), ('ACC');
```

Can someone please explain the above query in a simple clear way? Like what is happening first, etc.

Comment: I think the more pertinent question is what do you want it to return? It is a fairly straight forward query. "Return everything in dp with any matches in ep, where there are exactly 2 matches per dp.name"

Comment: Have you looked up `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` in any documentation?

Comment: @SeanRedmond I've looked up the docs, and I understand how Joins, Group By, and Having work on simple cases, but don't understand how they are working together.

Comment: @JenZhang which part do you have issues understanding? HAVING is applied on the result of GROUP BY

Comment: I think OP partly needs to understand the *flow* of evaluation in SQL. Generally, any query should be read in the following pattern: `FROM-WHERE-GROUP BY-HAVING-SELECT-ORDER BY`. Apply it to your query above. It's easy enough as it is.

Comment: @BK201 Thank you, that is pretty much all I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query groups all departments (from dp.name) and returns the number of employees in that department.

To visualize this you can draw out a single table with all the columns from both tables which is essentially your JOIN.

Then, you can draw out a second table by taking each department name distinctly one at a time from your above table and creating one row for each department (which is what the GROUP BY does) and checking the number of times that department shows in the first table (which is the count function).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the mysql EXPLAIN command? You can access it from the mysql console.